# Browsers and GPU

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, webkit, gpu, chromium

What kind of work does browsers off load to the GPU (when available)?
I mean does the GPU gets DOM (I guess not), or does the browser already calculates coordinates, in which case what does the GPU do. Or does the GPU only help in specific places (like canvas) but not in "normal" rendering.